# How do I create an array of buttons with a script?

Tags: button, livecode

I'd like to create an array of buttons with a script. This includes setting the size and position and assigning a mouseUp hander go them.

The mouseUp handler should be

```
on mouseUp
    go to card "aName"
end mouseUp
```

The list of names is in a text variable tCardNames. Each line has a card name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly different approach. The **repeat for each** form is more efficient for long lists than **repeat with**, but in this situation there would likely be no appreciable difference.

```
on createButtons
  repeat for each line tBtnName in tCardNames
    createNamedButton tBtnName
  end repeat
end createButtons

on createNamedButton pName
  create button pName
  set the script of btn pName to "on mouseUp" & cr & \
    "go cd " & quote & pName & quote & cr & \
    "end mouseUp"
  put the number of btn pName into tNum
  set the top of btn pName to (10 * 30 * (tNum - 1))
end createNamedButton
```

Answer (score 1):

The following script does the job

```
on createButtons
   repeat with i = 1 to the number of lines of tCardNames
      put line i of field "cardNames" into tName
      createNamedButton i, tName
   end repeat
end createButtons

on createNamedButton n, aName
   create button
   set the label of it to aName
   put "on mouseUp" & return into s
   put  "go to cd "  & quote & aName & quote& return after s
   put "end mouseUp" after s
   set the script of it to s
   put (10 + 30 * (n -1)) into tDistanceFromTop
   set the top of it to tDistanceFromTop
end createNamedButton
```

Answer (score 1):

That script should work fine, but since all the buttons have basically the same script, you could omit the script part of the handler, and assign them a behavior instead. This is a good example of when to use a behavior. The behavior button script would be something like this:

```
on mouseUp
  go cd (the label of the target)
end mouseUp
```

Create that button, name it "goCardBehavior", hide it, and in your original handler add this line instead of the part that writes the script:

```
set the behavior of it to the long ID of button "goCardBehavior"
```

One advantage of using behaviors is that when you need to change the script later, you only have to do it in one place.